# Obtain CRS from prj4string

Tags: r, spatial

I have a shape file, and i want to merge it with another data frame. But for this, i need to know the crs. But the shape file doesnt have the crs, just this description:

```
 Simple feature collection with 96 features and 9 fields
    geometry type:  POLYGON
    dimension:      XY
    bbox:           xmin: 313434.8 ymin: 7343789 xmax: 360663.2 ymax: 7416202
    epsg (SRID):    NA
    proj4string:    +proj=utm +zone=23 +south +ellps=aust_SA +units=m +no_defs
```

I tried to find the crs from the proj4string, but didnt find. Any one know how can i obtain this?

Comment: This question is not clear. What is that you want to do? This description is actually the shapefile's crs. It is "The Universal Transverse Mercator (UTM)"  zone:23. You should be able to retrieve the projection using `crs(shape.name)` or `shape.name@proj4string`.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, if you install the `rgdal` package, you can look up the name of the coordinate reference system with the `proj4string` in the shapefile metadata you provided:

```
library(rgdal)
showEPSG('+proj=utm +zone=23 +south +ellps=aust_SA +units=m +no_defs')
```

But this returns nothing useful in this case:
`"OGRERR_UNSUPPORTED_SRS"`
From the proj4 string, you have a UTM projection in southern zone 23.  Googling the proj4string led me here:https://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Brazilian_Coordinate_Reference_Systems

Also, here is more help explaining the use of coordinate reference systems in R: https://www.nceas.ucsb.edu/~frazier/RSpatialGuides/OverviewCoordinateReferenceSystems.pdf